# Error injecting Angular 1.4.7 cookie service

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I've researched this online but cannot get it to work.

I followed this online doc below to inject the `$cookies` service into my login controller, but I keep getting error: `[$injector:modulerr]`

[cookie injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('rage', ['ngCookies']).controller('LoginCtrl',
        ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$cookies', '$modalInstance', '$q', 'datacontext', 'userService', authenticate]);

    function authenticate($rootScope, $scope, $cookies, $modalInstance, $q, datacontext, userService) {

        var login = this;

        // OK,CANCEL CLICK EVENTS FROM MODAL !!!
        $scope.ok = function () {
                       
            var user = {userId: login.userId, pswd: login.pswd};
            $modalInstance.close(user);
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    }
})();
```

I've upgraded Angular from 1.3.5 to 1.4.7 and my index.html has :

```html
<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->      
<script src="Scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular scripts-->
<!--<script src="Scripts/angular/angular-1.3.5.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="Scripts/angular/angular-1.4.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular/angular-cookies-1.4.7.min.js"></script>

<!-- angular-ui-bootstrap -->
<!--<script src="Scripts/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
```

Advice is greatly appreciated...

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngCookies` is an *external* module: you have to include `angular-cookie.js` script in the index.

Apart from that, I see that you injected `$modalInstance`, which is probably the service from `ui-bootstrap`. You will have to include also `angular-ui-bootstrap` script, and add the module as a dependency.

To sum up, your *index.html* should look like:

```
<script src="scripts/.../angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/.../angular-cookie.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/.../ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

And the module declaration:

```
angular.module('rage', ['ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

Comment: yes indeed ! I literally just found that out, and downloaded angular-cookies.js, version 1.4.7 to line up with Angular 1.4.7 as well. I'm still trying to get rid of some errors though.

Comment: I'd like to set a cookie expiry, and it appears that version 1.4.7 has it but there are no examples - i.e. https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider . Any ideas ?

Comment: var expireDate = expireDate = moment().add(3, "month").format();
    $cookies.put("cookieName", cookieString, { 'expires': expireDate });